# vector::push_back <MyClass> not work for non default constructor

Tags: c++, qt

i have a  `Controls` class that have default constructor and copy constructor and other constructor ,and an assignment operator , and i want to create array of my class using vector . When i resize my vector i get the objects initialized correctly ; but when i want to create my objects using non default constructor i get this error ,

> pure virtual method called
>       terminate called without an active exception

```
Controls.h

class Controls : public QObject
{

private:

    QHBoxLayout Layout ;
    string Controlname;
    std::auto_ptr<QLabel> Label ;
    std::auto_ptr<QSlider> Slider ;
    std::auto_ptr<QSpinBox> Spin ;

public:

    Controls(QLayout &Parent , string name , const int &Default_value);
    Controls(const Controls &copy);
    Controls();
    ~Controls();

    QLabel *const Get_Label()const { return Label.get() ; }
    QSlider *const Get_Slider()const { return Slider.get() ; }
    QSpinBox *const Get_Spin()const { return Spin.get() ; }
    QHBoxLayout *const Get_Layout() {return &Layout;}

    void SetValue(const int &newvalue);

    Controls &operator= (const Controls &copy);


};
```

Controls.cpp

```
Controls &Controls::operator= (const Controls &copy)
{
    Label = std::auto_ptr<QLabel> ( new QLabel() ) ;
    Slider = std::auto_ptr<QSlider> ( new QSlider() ) ;
    Spin = std::auto_ptr<QSpinBox> ( new QSpinBox() ) ;

    Slider->setValue(copy.Get_Slider()->value());
    Slider->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
    Label->setText(QString ("unamed"));
    Spin->setValue(copy.Get_Spin()->value());


    Layout.addWidget(Label.get() , 0 , 0);
    Layout.addWidget(Slider.get() , 0 , 0);
    Layout.addWidget(Spin.get() , 0 , 0);

    QObject::connect(Slider.get() , SIGNAL(valueChanged(int) ) , Spin.get() , SLOT(setValue(int)));
    QObject::connect(Spin.get() , SIGNAL(valueChanged(int) ) , Slider.get() , SLOT(setValue(int)));


    return *this ;
}
Controls::Controls(const Controls &copy)
{
    *this = copy ;
}
Controls::Controls()
{

    Label = std::auto_ptr<QLabel> ( new QLabel() ) ;
    Slider = std::auto_ptr<QSlider> ( new QSlider() ) ;
    Spin = std::auto_ptr<QSpinBox> ( new QSpinBox() ) ;

    Slider->setValue(0);
    Slider->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
    Label->setText(QString ("unamed"));
    Spin->setValue(0);


    Layout.addWidget(Label.get() , 0 , 0);
    Layout.addWidget(Slider.get() , 0 , 0);
    Layout.addWidget(Spin.get() , 0 , 0);

    QObject::connect(Slider.get() , SIGNAL(valueChanged(int) ) , Spin.get() , SLOT(setValue(int)));
    QObject::connect(Spin.get() , SIGNAL(valueChanged(int) ) , Slider.get() , SLOT(setValue(int)));
}
Controls::Controls(QLayout &Parent , string name , const int &Default_value)
{
    Controlname = name ;

    Label = std::auto_ptr<QLabel> ( new QLabel() ) ;
    Slider = std::auto_ptr<QSlider> ( new QSlider() ) ;
    Spin = std::auto_ptr<QSpinBox> ( new QSpinBox() ) ;

    Slider->setValue(Default_value);
    Slider->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
    Label->setText(QString (name.c_str()));
    Spin->setValue(Default_value);


    Layout.addWidget(Label.get() , 0 , 0);
    Layout.addWidget(Slider.get() , 0 , 0);
    Layout.addWidget(Spin.get() , 0 , 0);

    QObject::connect(Slider.get() , SIGNAL(valueChanged(int) ) , Spin.get() , SLOT(setValue(int)));
    QObject::connect(Spin.get() , SIGNAL(valueChanged(int) ) , Slider.get() , SLOT(setValue(int)));

    Parent.addItem(&Layout);

}

void Controls::SetValue(const int &newvalue)
{
    Slider.get()->setValue(newvalue);
}
Controls::~Controls()
{

}
```

main.cpp
......
.

```
   vector <Controls> i ;
      i.resize(2 ); // this is work 

     i.push_back(Controls(layout , "WHITE_BALANCE_RED_V" ,12);// this is not working
```

Comment: I guess it's just editing problem, but this line is bad already, it should be "i.push_back(Controls(layout , "WHITE_BALANCE_RED_V" ,12));"

Comment: sorry! i forget point comma (i edit it now) , but i use it in my real code! and i get output : pure virtual method called terminate called without an active exception when i use push_back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `std::vector` and non-default constructors.
You did not provide the whole code, but I assume this is the continuation of the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929533/stdvector-do-not-create-list-of-my-class-type/12930251#12930251).

Your `Controls::operator=` is invalid, it creates copies of `QWidgets`, and puts them into brand new `QLayout`. `Controls` object that you pass to `push_back` is temporary object that is destroyed after the call and it's copy is put into vector. But destroyed object's `QWidget` members are put into `QLayout`, which is not destroyed and which is added to the widget you try to show (`Panel`). After temporary `Controls` object is destroyed, `Panel->show()` calls Panel's `QLayout` methods that try to access already deleted widgets.

Do you really need to save **copies** of your `Controls` objects in your vector? If you store pointers, that would get rid of your problem. Why do you need that vector at all?

And once again, **do not** use `auto_ptr`, it's deprecated and you don't need it to correctly manage deletion of `QObjects`.

Comment: Your Controls::operator= is invalid ; can you explain witch part is invalid and hank you

Comment: I already described - in `operator=` you create a new layout for destination `Controls` object and put copies of your widgets there. When source `Controls` object (that you copy from) is destroyed, widgets are also deleted (thanks to `auto_ptr`), but pointers to them are stored in `QVBoxLayout layout` object that you created on stack before. `layout` is then set up into `Panel`. When you call `Panel->show()` it calls methods of `QLayout` for `layout` object, which, in turn, tries to call methods of deleted widgets.

Comment: Please describe, why do you need to store copies of `Controls` objects in this vector? Can you store pointers? Do you need to store them at all?

Comment: i don't want to store copies of Controls , i want to store new Controls object .

Comment: Consider storing pointers then (but not auto_ptrs, you may store raw pointers or shared_ptrs or QSharedPtrs, whatever you like). `std::vector::resize` works just because it either don't copy anything (there's enough memory to just expand the vector storage) or because it copies default constructed `Controls` objects which are not used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I think the problem is with your auto_ptr variables. You should check if it is really the way how you want to treat your object pointers. I would rather stick with the shared_ptr or unique_ptr. In the latter case however, you don't want to have copy constructor at all, as there could be only one owner of the pointers.

[C++ std::auto_ptr copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971818/c-stdauto-ptr-copy-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you are implementing your copy semantics correctly, and the use of `std::auto_ptr` as a data member is kind of an "alert sign".

Are your `Controls` really deep-copyable?

Maybe you should just use `scoped_ptr` instead of `auto_ptr` data members, ban copy declaring *private* copy constructor and *private* `operator=`, and use `vector<shared_ptr<Controls>>` ?

(Or use C++11 and move semantics, and so use `unique_ptr` instead of `auto_ptr`, and just use compiler automatically generated move operations?)

Answer (score 0):

When using `auto_ptr` you should use `release` not `get` to pass the pointer to new owner:

Not this in `Controls::Controls(QLayout &Parent , string name , const int &Default_value)`:

```
Layout.addWidget(Label.get() , 0 , 0);
```

But that:

```
Layout.addWidget(Label.release() , 0 , 0);
```

Otherwise - your `auto_ptr` are deleting the pointers at the end of scope of this constructor.